# How i can use the htmlspecial character before the $_SERVER['REQUEST-url'] and prevent from hacking attacks

Tags: php, html, forms, xss

```
action="htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER["SignInSignUpPHP.php"] ;)";
```

What i can use in the action="" ?

If i want to prevent from hacking attacks ?
Please guided me i was so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very large topic. If you want to prevent hacking attack you have to make security system planning for your project.

If i do answer straight to your question, you do not be worry about `action=""` attribute, think how to filter your data when you get it to destination file or place.

For EXAMPLE When you get data with post or get method you can filter:

```
$get = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

or

```
$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Think, hackers is not only dangerous attackers, there are also users. They doing weird things and you must consider every step of they can do.

But you must know that there is no ONE_MAGIC_FUNCTION to prevent hacker's and user's attack.
You have to learn, read about what is best practices for security and etc.

There is so many information about that in internet, you have to investigate, read about it. You can also make some search around this "best practices php security".